# How to test my app on an iOS device which has a disabled Safari browser?

Tags: ios, mdm

A client of ours reported that a certain feature does not work for them as they don't have Safari installed on their company phones.

I didn't get enough info out of them, but I can only assume that they use [MDM Restrictions](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/deployment-education/eduee8624eef/web) to prevent their employees from browsing the web.

This is problematic because our app is generally distributed for internal company use and uses a [Web Authentication](https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-Android), meaning their employees cannot log in since the authentication flow cannot be started due to disabled Safari.

We'll solve this by implementing a fallback native login page, which uses our API to authenticate the user, but I have no idea how to test this, as there is seemingly no way to disable Safari on a normal iPhone or Simulator, which is not controlled by MDM.

Is there a simple way to emulate this? I don't want to go through the hassle of obtaining an iPhone which is controlled by a MDM just to test this one feature.

Comment: You can use Apple Comfigurator to install a management payload. Although I would be surprised if disabling safari also disabled ASWebAuthenticationSession (which is what you should be using for authentication)

Comment: @Paulw11 For some reason, we use external agent for authentication flow, meaning it actually does use a Safari window instead of the recommended `ASWebAuthenticationSession`. That's another debate though :)

Comment: That's why it doesn't work then. You should really adopt ASWebAuthenticationSession. It will probably resolve your problem and it is a much better user experience that bouncing out to safari and back

Comment: @Paulw11 I will definitely consider that. I am not sure why we are doing it this way, it's been a couple of years since implementation and I think we had our reasons. I believe it might have had something to do with being unable to automatically launch the user into the Auth flow, and the user had to press a login button manually. Either way, thanks for pointing me to Apple Configurator, I will check that out regardless.